# javascript guidance re arranging functions into files

Tags: javascript

Have written a large system in ColdFusion/Javascript/MySQL.  There is lots of Javascript.  The few functions which are long are separated into cases.  Currently I have all the js in 3 files, depending on the section of the application to which they refer.

Every now and again, some function which tested okay before turns out not to be working (I might have changed something elsewhere to cause that problem, without realizing I had to retest).

Okay, I deserve that, but when one js function in the file stops working, sometimes others do as well.  So unexpectedly something I was counting on to validate things, or prevent a submit in the presence of errors does not work.

I've thought of breaking up the js so that any javascript function which is used by just one program will be resident there, and I would use the files with several js functions only for those that several programs have to access.  That would insulate my functions somewhat from problems occurring elsewhere.

Is this approach recommended?  Could someone offer good reasons for or against it?  Or is there a way to "firewall" my functions so that problems with one do not spill over into another?

I'm feeling that the js is a weak link in my system -- that I can't trust it; yet I need it, so I have to find a way to make things more stable.  Any and all suggestions to help would be much appreciated.

The suggestion "get better at Javascript" has already occurred to me.  I am trying.  Meanwhile, my needs are not very demanding.  All my functions do simple things and are written in a pretty straightforward way.  Yet I am having all this trouble.

Comment: Don't simply break functions up into files. Create modules (normally a module is an entire file) and use some system or approach for uniform access (of which there are several). Modules should be self-contained insofar as they should not break a non-dependent, ever (but may have dependencies on other modules). Modules should be testable as stand-alone entities with refined interfaces.

Comment: Use a front-end JS framework, there are lots of them. Try them all and use one that best fits the job. Not one is perfect, but it could be just right for the job.